# Action Link argument not passing to controller correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am unable to pass argument str in the view code to my controller. It comes through as null. I want it to pass as "".

Any help?

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string str, string sortOrder)
{

    if (str == "")
        return View(db.Ports.OrderByDescending(model => model.PurchaseDate));

    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
    var investments = from s in context.Investments
                   select s;
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            investments = investments.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
            break;
        case "Date":
            investments = investments.OrderBy(s => s.PurchaseDate);
            break;
        case "date_desc":
            investments = investments.OrderByDescending(s => s.PurchaseDate);
            break;
        default:
            investments = investments.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
            break;
    }
    return View(investments.ToList());
}
```

View Code:

```
@model StockHoldings.Models.Investments

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    @*<script> src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' </script>*@    
</head>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Investments</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LastName, (SelectList)ViewBag.LastNames)

                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fund, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fund, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fund, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Shares, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Shares, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Shares, new { id = "sharesID", name = "Shares", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Shares, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchasePrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchasePrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PurchasePrice, new { id = "purchasepriceID", name = "PurchasePrice", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchasePrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchaseAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PurchaseAmount, new { id = "purchaseamountID", name = "PurchaseAmount", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchaseAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    *@

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
```

Here's the link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Investments", "Index", "Investments", new { str = "", sortOrder = "Date" }, null)

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Alter The Argument in Action Method make the string str is Optional Parameter  to  empty .it work
 public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string str = "")